# execute x number of Actions each every n milliseconds

Tags: c#, multithreading, action

I have a program where I let the user create several functions and once he creates all the functions I run them every x milliseconds. In other words I have something like:

```
// functionsToExecute is of type = List<Action>
// x = some integer
while(true){

   foreach(Action action in functionsToExecute)
   {
       action();
   }

   Thread.Sleep(x);
}
```

Now I will like for the user to decide how long to wait per function. For example if the user creates 2 functions he might want the first function to run every 500 milliseconds the next one every 1500. I was thinking about creating two threads for this scenario and then have the same implementation. **But what if the user creates 50 functions? I will need 50 threads!**

**In short** I will like to execute x number of Actions each every n milliseconds... What will be the best way to create such algorithm? For example if I have 3 Actions I will like to execute the first action every 200 milliseconds, the next one every 500 milliseconds and the last one every 1000 milliseconds.

Maybe I need something similar to the `SetTimout` function in javascript

Comment: You realise that currently, "every `n` milliseconds" means "with a `n` millisecond gap between one run finishing and the next run starting"? Do you want this behaviour to continue, or to genuinely have a function _started_ every `n` milliseconds?

Comment: There's almost always a better solution than Sleep. For instance, your problem could be solved with a single System Timer set to go off at the next time the soonest of the functions need to fire.

Comment: I guess I want this behavior to continue. I cannot execute to methods at the same time I need a lock because the actions eather write or read to a board (chip). This functions may help the user graph the value of a variable in the board every 500 milliseconds. I will like the user to decide how long to excecute that funcion...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using .NET 4.5 and your code is not time-critical, then you can easily do this with the Task Parallel Library:

```
static Task Repeat (List<Action> actions, CancellationToken token, int delay)
{
    var tasks = new List<Task> ();
    var cts = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource (token);

    foreach (var action in actions) {
        var task = Task.Factory.StartNew (async () => {
            while (true) {
                cts.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested ();
                await Task.Delay (delay, cts.Token).ConfigureAwait (false);
                action ();
            }
        });
        tasks.Add (task);
    }

    return Task.WhenAll (tasks);
}
```

Ideally, you should also make your actions async to properly support cancellation.

The .NET runtime automatically takes care of thread scheduling, but there's no guarantee that your action will be executed after *exactly* the requested timeout.  It will be executed after at least that time has elapsed and there's an idle thread available.

Answer (score 3):

i would consider using a [`ThreadPool`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) ([walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dasc8as%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)). Create each thread to process and have it repeat based on the timeout they're looking for. You can also store the [`ManualResetEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for when you need the thread(s) to stop.